# Normalization of matrix with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix of the form:

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \end{array} \right) $$

The rows of the matrix add up to 1. That is $ a+b+c = 1$, $ d+e+f= 1$ and $ g+h+i= 1$

I need to normalize it such that the mean of all the elements $a$ to $i$ is a fixed value $M$ and the standard deviation is $S$. At the same time, the sum of the elements in the rows must keep being 1.

I can do both things separately but I can't figure a good way of doing both at the same time. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What operations are allowed? If there are no limitations you could just replace the entire matrix with one that satisfies your requirements. Besides, if each row sums to $1$ then all the values will sum to $3$. $M$ cannot be any other value.

Comment: Sue me if I'm wrong, but there is no choice in $M$. The equations already fix $M=\frac13$.

Comment: There is no limitation in the operations but every operation has to be applied to all the elements in the matrix, or at least row by row. Is is possible to do this?